# Matplotlib: inverse affine transformation to get an equal aspect with different x and y limits

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-algebra, affinetransform

I have the 2D coordinates of a geometric shape as `x` and `y` arrays. Using a combination of translation and rotation I can get the shape rotated about its geometric center by a given angle `alpha` (See below for a minimal example).

As shown in the code below, this can be achieved by first shifting the geometric center of the shape to the origin of the coordinates, then applying the rotation (multiplying by the 2D rotation matrix) then translating it back to its original position.

In this example, let's assume that the shape is a rectangle:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin, linspace, concatenate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def rotate(x, y, alpha):
    """
    Rotate the shape by an angle alpha (given in degrees)
    """
    # Get the center of the shape
    x_center = (x.max() + x.min()) / 2.0
    y_center = (y.max() + y.min()) / 2.0

    # Shifting the center of the shape to the origin of coordinates
    x0 = x - x_center
    y0 = y - y_center
    angle_rad = np.deg2rad(alpha)
    rot_mat = np.array([
    [cos(angle_rad), -sin(angle_rad)],
    [sin(angle_rad), cos(angle_rad)]
    ])
    xy = np.vstack((x0, y0))
    xnew, ynew = rot_mat @ xy

    # translate it back to its original location
    xnew += x_center
    ynew += y_center

    return xnew, ynew

z0, z1, z2, z3 = 4 + 0.6*1j, 4 + 0.8*1j, 8 + 0.8*1j, 8 + 0.6*1j
xy = concatenate((
                linspace(z0, z1, 10, endpoint=False),
                linspace(z1, z2, 10, endpoint=False),
                linspace(z2, z3, 10, endpoint=False),
                linspace(z3, z0, 10, endpoint=True)
          ))

x = xy.real
y = xy.imag

xrot, yrot = rotate(x, y, alpha=-45.0)

# The x and y limits
xlow, xup = 0, 10
ylow, yup = -1.5, 3.0


plt.plot(x, y, label='original shape')
plt.plot(xrot, yrot, label='rotated shape')
plt.xlim((xlow, xup))
plt.ylim((ylow, yup))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

We get the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the shape gets rotated but it is stretched/skewed as well because the aspect was not set to `equal`. we could check that by setting:

```py
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

And this shows the rotated shape without being skewed:

[image]

---

The problem is that I am plotting this shape with other data that has an `x` range much larger than the `y` range. So, setting an equal aspect is not a solution in this case.

To be more precise, I want the rotated shape (orange color) in the first figure to show up correctly like the second figure. My approach is to find the **inverse skew matrix** in the first figure (resulting from the difference between x and y limits) and multiply it by the rotated shape to get the expected result.

Unfortunately, Using trial and error I couldn't get the correct skew matrix.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
From a linear algebra perspective, how to express that deformation of the rotated shape in the first figure in terms of skewing and scaling transformations?

Comment: Your polygon is defined by its 4 vertices (meaning their respective coordinates). Using an equal representation for both axis shows your polygon is a rectangle. Using a non-equal representation will change internal angles in the polygon and therefore it looks like it is no longer a rectangle, but it is. If you wish to stay in this non-equal representation and still show a rectangle, you will have to modify the vertices coordinates, which entirely changes your object, meaning that it will not map back to a rectangle in the equal representation. You could use a log-log format for your axes.

Comment: @Patol75: Yes, I want to modify the vertices by multiplying the rotated shape by the inverse skew matrix (or whatever deformation matrix)

Comment: OK, but before doing this, would you mind trying a log-log representation?

Comment: The confusing bit about your question is that once you rotate the rectangle in screen coordinates, it will not be a rectangle any more (unless you use equal aspect). But your code suggests that the vertices carry a meaning in data coordinates. This means that the desired output is something which lost its meaning. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: In other words, What is the matrix that we should multiply the rotated shape to get it as expected (rotated but not deformed) without changing `xlim` and `ylim`.

Comment: Is this a math question, or is this a question about how to get the desired visual?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I want to get the desired visual without caring about the math (I will change the post if that is necessary).

Comment: *What is the matrix that we should multiply...* The fundamental problem here is that the rotation matrix would not be like a normal [2D rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) which has 4 values that depend only on the polar angle (`theta` in the link). This matrix would have 4 values that vary based on the polar angle and the radial distance to each point - but in the `x` component more than the `y`. It is possible to create such a matrix on the fly, but it will be.... difficult

Answer (score 1):

When performing the desired rotation, the vertices of the rectangle will lose their meaning in data coordinates, and the initial rectangle will become a trapezoid. Apparently this is desired. So the question becomes essentially how to perform a rotation in screen coordinates about a given point `center` in data coordinates.

The solution might look a little complicated, which is due to a callback being used. This is necessary, to keep the center point in screen coordinates synchronized with possible axis limit changes.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D 

x, y = (4, 0.6)
dx, dy = (4, 0.2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# The x and y limits
xlow, xup = 0, 10
ylow, yup = -1.5, 3.0
ax.set(xlim=(xlow, xup), ylim=(ylow, yup))

rect1 = plt.Rectangle((x,y), width=dx, height=dy, facecolor="none", edgecolor="C0")
ax.add_patch(rect1)

rect2 = plt.Rectangle((x,y), width=dx, height=dy, facecolor="none", edgecolor="C1")
ax.add_patch(rect2) 

def lim_change(evt=None):
    center = (x+dx/2, y+dy/2)
    trans = ax.transData + Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(*ax.transData.transform_point(center), -45)
    rect2.set_transform(trans)
lim_change()   
cid = ax.callbacks.connect("xlim_changed", lim_change)
cid = ax.callbacks.connect("ylim_changed", lim_change)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Forget your data... the output is wrong in data coordinates anyways, as pointed out in the comments already.

Comment: If you rotate your airfoil and show it in a non-equal aspect axes, it will be wrong. I will not help further obtaining wrong results.

Comment: The solution in my opinion is to use another axis with an equal aspect just to plot the rotated shape on it using something like : `ax2 = ax.twinx(); ax2.set_aspect('equal'); ax2.plot(xrot, yrot)` while keeping the original shape in the first axis.